# Stop renaming when copy/pasting

Tags: copy-paste, visual-studio-code

If I Ctrl-A, Ctrl-C a file (or copy the entire contents of a file), call it foo.txt, then do a Ctrl-A, Ctrl-V into a different file (replace the entire contents of that file with what I copied), call it bar.txt, VSCode will automatically create a new file called "foo-1.txt", with the pasted code in it, leaving bar.txt untouched. This is incredibly irritating, because this maneuver is always intentional for me. I'm assuming it's some kind of feature to prevent people from accidentally overwriting a file when they just want to make a copy of one. Thus, I suspect there is a setting to change this behavior. Does anyone know what that setting is?

Comment: I did a little more fiddling and figured out exactly when it happens.

When it happens I click on a file in the explorer (I do NOT double click). Then I hit ctrl-a (this highlights the contents of the document, but I noticed it's a lighter shade of blue than usual). I then hit ctrl-c. I then click on another file in the same way (no double clicking), ctrl-a in the same way (same light blue), then hit ctrl-v, and then instead of writing over the contents of the new file, it creates a new file with the name of the file I was copying from with a -1 (if I do it again, -2, etc).

Comment: If I double click, OR I click then click inside the editor pane, then when I ctrl-A it's the normal bright blue and it works fine (works fine only if I PASTE this way, copying this way makes no difference)